# Java stopping do-while loop when user pressed a button

Tags: java

new to Java. So I want the user to be able to stop the payment process anytime they want to by typing "quit". How can I achieve that? Tried the do-while loop but its not working. Here is the code

```
  public void payItems() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String name = s.next();
        s.nextLine();
        //where should I put word = s.next
        System.out.println("Enter address: ");
        String address = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter card number: ");
        int cardNo = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter card expiration date: (DDMMYY)");
        int expirationDate = s.nextInt();
        Customer newcust = new Customer(name, address, cardNo, expirationDate);
    } while (!word.equals("quit"));
}
```

Comment: I do not understan in detail what you want. Do you want to stop process if user entered "quit" in name or address or ...?

Comment: yes, so if the user typed quit then the loop stops immediately, otherwise the user will keep entering their details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to do somethink like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter name: ");
String name = s.next();
s.nextLine();
if (name.equals("quit") 
   return;
//where should I put word = s.next
System.out.println("Enter address: ");
String address = s.nextLine();
if (address.equals("quit") 
   return;
System.out.println("Enter card number: ");
int cardNo = s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter card expiration date: (DDMMYY)");
int expirationDate = s.nextInt();
Customer newcust = new Customer(name, address, cardNo, expirationDate);
```

but it doesnt work for cardNo and expiration because these are int values, so you can not enter "quit".

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can change your code as follows

```
 boolean status=true;
    do {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter address: ");
        String address = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter card number: ");
        int cardNo = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter card expiration date: (DDMMYY)");
        int expirationDate = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You want to add more or quit(type continue to add another, type quit to exit): ");
        String word=s.next();
        if(word.equals("quit")){
            status=false;
        }
    } while (status);
```

Comment: Thanks for that fix. But yeah, my question is how can I stop the loop. Am I supposed to put word = s.nextLine every 2 lines (after String name = s.next();) and so on

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I want. In your code, it asks the user to quit after the user entered the expiry date. I want the user to be able to quit anytime they want by typing quit. Jens already provided me the answer. Thanks for responding though. Cheers :)